# Seeing previous register values in ollydbg possible?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I wanted to know if one can see old register values in Ollydbg in the register window. I mean, for example, I have the register value of `eax` like `eax=12345678`. And, now, let say that I go to the next instruction, and then to next instruction and so on... Lets also say, that `eax` is changing all the time and after a couple of instructions and changements of `eax`.

I want to know the former value of `eax`, namely `eax=1234568`, how can I do that in Ollydbg ?

Answer (score 3):

The ***[Run trace](http://www.ollydbg.de/Tut_rtr.htm)*** feature of ollydbg can be used to know the values of registers in a previous execution step. During Run trace code is executed step by step, and debugger protocols every command, together with registers and flags.

Here is a tutorial on tracing https://sites.google.com/site/corkami/ollydbg-tracing